# Setting up a workspace using Team Explorer Everywhere on Linux

Tags: linux, version-control, command-line, tfs, tf-cli

Im having trouble creating a workspace and downloading the files from a Team Foundation Server using the Team Explorer Everywhere command line client (TEE-CLC-10.0.0). I've gotten as far as creating workspace:

```
$ ../tfs/TEE-CLC-10.0.0/tf -login:secretUsername,secretPassword -server:http://secretHost:8080 workspace -new KOLOBI
Workspace 'KOLOBI2' created.
```

Then I want to download files from the server to my workspace:

```
$ ../tfs/TEE-CLC-10.0.0/tf -login:secretUsername,secretPassword -server:http://secretHost:8080 get -recursive -all -force .
An argument error occurred: Items must reside in a workspace that has been previously used on this computer.
```

I guess I'm missing one step which is to add local directories to the workspace or something like that. But I can't figure out how to do it to be able to download the files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to create working folder mappings between your local folder and the server items you wish to correspond to.

For example:

```
tf workfold -map -login:secretUsername,secretPassword -server:http://secretHost:8080 -workspace:KOLOBI '$/TeamProject/Project' '/home/me/project'
```

Then from the `/home/me/project` directory (or whatever you pick), you can just execute `tf get .`

Comment: how would you do this in windows? I changed the home/me/project path to a windows directory but i get the message: workfold requires zero, one, or two path arguments

Comment: @PAULDAWG could you post your full command line?  it sounds like you have a space somewhere that isn't being quoted.

Comment: tf workfold /map /login:secretusername@domain.com,secretPassword /server:http://serverurl:8080/tfs workspace:EEMXP01 '$/' 'C:\EEMTFS Source\'

Comment: I added a switch to workspace and now it says my workspace doesn't exist, so i guess im onto a different problem now

Comment: @I am trying to map the TFS workspace to local by using this comment  tf workfold /map /login:username,pwd /server:http://servername:8080/tfs /workspace:'$/source/app/TFS_Label' 'C:\TFS_Label'   but getting the error saying  "An argument error occurred: workfold requires zero, one, or two path arguments." Please help on this issue..thanks.

Comment: You are supplying a server path to the workspace argument.  Please create a workspace, use that name for that argument (eg, `/workspace:NAME`) and then use the server path as a separate argument.